# C++ Builder XE3 run & crash BEFORE the main()

Tags: c++, c++builder, access-violation, execution, c++builder-xe3

I have some troubles with Embarcadero C++ Builder XE3. When I run my program, I have an access violation BEFORE the first instruction in the main...So I can't debug, it's very weird.

I used to have this problem a couple of weeks ago : I was forced to full rebuild the entire projet (even if only a comma was missing...) and the violation didn't occurs anymore. I solved it by ckecking the option "Disable incremental link".

I was very happy, but today, the problem is back, and whatever I do, my application crash before enterring in the main ...

Does anyone have an idea ? It's a big project, so I can't really post an exemple because I don't really know what to show...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do a clean (manually delete all .obj files and other build files). Another thing that can cause this problem is if some files are compiled with runtime linking of the RTL and/or packages, and some files compiled with static linking. Yet another thing is if the exe depends on a DLL that is not found.  To debug it, cut down your project to just `int main() {}`, get that working, and then work from there.  I'd also highly recommend using source control (e.g. `git`) so that you can save a known-good build and quickly identify what might have changed.

Comment: If it's happening before `main`, then it's most likely the initialisation of a static/global variable. Be very careful of the "initialisation order fiasco", where the initialisation of one static variable uses another which hasn't yet been initialised. Avoid global variables if you can.

Comment: If it is a static init problem then the debugger would step into it

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Both of you helped me :)

I use SVN for source control, so I restored the previous version, and check one by one each modification...

And, as you expected, it's a static initialisation :

.h
class MyClass {
    public std::string MyString;
}

.cpp :
string MyClass::MyString = NULL;

I didn't know it was impossible...I replaced NULL with an empty string, and it's now OK !

string MyClass::MyString = "";

Thank you two again :)

Comment: You do realize that `std::string` is a class that does its own initialization, right?  You don't need to manually initialize it with a blank value, it is already blank to begin with.

Comment: Do you have a bug in a constructor of a static global object ???  These are all executed before `main()` invocation.

Comment: Since you fixed your issue, you should post an official answer and checked it so it will be easy to see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a bug in a constructor of a static global object.  These constructors are all executed before getting into `main()`, so this can happen without being a runtime environment or a compiler bug.

As you told, debugging these is difficult as you probably don't know which class is failing, and probably you don't have exception info also.

As you say it's a large project, perhaps you have to resign to use large project toolkits/methodologies to deal with these problems, like **unit testing** and **lean methodologies** (like **scrum** or the like).

With the information you post I think this is the most can be said.